# Spring WebSocket returning an unlogged 403

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket, spring-boot

There is a 403 being returned from my Spring WebSocket though I'm not sure why, Spring Security is not currently on the class path.

note: I started writing this issue and then turned on full Spring Boot debug, here's the last 3 lines of log it emits.

```
2015-08-23 14:38:30.263 DEBUG 32271 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /socket/info
2015-08-23 14:38:30.270 DEBUG 32271 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/socket/info]
2015-08-23 14:39:08.791  INFO 32271 --- [eBrokerSockJS-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

here's the response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, x-auth-token, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
X-Application-Context: application
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2015 18:01:10 GMT
```

here's the request

```
GET /socket/info?t=1440352870279 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: NXSESSIONID=174bf31b-e199-44e3-bae8-f5f44ad6ee90
```

Here's my WebSocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker( final MessageBrokerRegistry config ) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker( "/topic" );
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes( "/app" );
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints( final StompEndpointRegistry registry ) {
    registry.addEndpoint( "/socket" ).withSockJS();
}

}
```

visiting http://localhost:8080 displays "Welcome to SockJS!" so I believe that's working. StompJS is emitting `Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/socket` after the 403.

here's my javascript.

```
var SockJS = require( 'sockjs-client' );
var sock = new SockJS( 'http://localhost:8080/socket' );
var Stomp = require( 'stompjs' );
var stompClient = Stomp.over( sock );
stompClient.connect( {}, function( frame ) {
    console.log( 'Connected: ' + frame );
    stompClient.subscribe( '/topic/stations/create', function() {
        console.log( 'subscribed' );
    } );
} );
```

stomp emits this `Opening Web Socket...`, but never reaches connected

What am I missing? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there is a second allow origin, that I needed to allow, specifically for websockets. I have an `allowOrigin` in my `application.properties` and then used setter injection on my configuration because constructor injection doesn't work on this bean type. Then all I had to add was `setAllowedOrigins( ... )` prior to calling `withSockJs`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

private URI allowOrigin;

@Inject // constructor injection not working in this class, use setter injection instead
public void setAllowOrigin(  @Value( "${allowOrigin}" ) final URI allowOrigin ) {
    this.allowOrigin = Objects.requireNonNull( allowOrigin );
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker( final MessageBrokerRegistry config ) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker( "/topic" );
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes( "/app" );
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints( final StompEndpointRegistry registry ) {
    registry.addEndpoint( "/socket" )
            .setAllowedOrigins( allowOrigin.toString() )
            .withSockJS();
}

}
```